# How to make threading.Thread's start() call a method other than run()

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class which has two methods `run()` and `run_forever()`, the latter calling the former repeatedly. I would like to run `run_forever()` for different instances of the class on separate threads, but so far I haven't been able to deviate from `threading.Thread`'s default behavior of calling `run()`.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
import time
import threading

class Controller(object):
    def run(self):
        print("Running once...")

    def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            self.run()
            time.sleep(1)

class ThreadController(Controller, threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, target=self.run_forever)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_controller = ThreadController()
    thread_controller.start()
    thread_controller.join()
```

If I run this script, it prints `Running once...` once, and doesn't continue to print it every second like I intended by setting `target=self.run_forever` in the initialization of `threading.Thread`. How might I modify this code to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Why do you have `run_forever`? Can't you just put loop into `run`?

Comment: Try using .start().

Comment: You are trying to mix the Controller API into the Thread API but they have method name collisions so it won't work. If you can't change Controller, then you'll have to settle for a thread object that contains the controller. The easy way to do that is `threading.Thread(target=Controll().run_forever)` as mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop inheriting from `Controller`:

```
controller = Controller()
thread = threading.Thread(target=controller.run_forever)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are de-facto overwriting the `run` method of the thread: Your `ThreadController` inherits from `Controller` and from `Thread`, and the `Controller` class implements its own `run`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run):

> The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument

But your `run` is not invoking anything (doesn't do anything with the *target*). It just prints *Running once...* That single `print` that you see is the `Thread` trying to execute its `run()` method. Well... *trying to* and actually succeeding. **;-)**

Something that comes to mind to fix this (although I *personally* would probably change the code some more and try to avoid the double inheritance) would be changing the name of your `Controller.run` to something like `.do`:

```
class Controller(object):
    def do(self):
        print("Running once...")

    def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            self.do()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was mentioned, I would also not prefer the multiple inheritance, but make the class with the run method to be the thread itself. That makes the `ThreadController` actually what its name suggests. May I suggest the following refractured code:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, target=self.run_forever)

    def do(self):
        print("Running once...")

    def run_forever(self):
        while True:
            self.do()
            time.sleep(1)

class ThreadController(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        c = MyThread()
        c.start()
        c.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    thread_controller = ThreadController()
```

That of course apart from the fact that one could rename `run_forever` to `run` and omit the `target` argument to the constructor, but I respect the title of this post :-).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want Controller to inherit from Thread, and then don't override `run`;

```
from threading import Thread

class Controller(Thread):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run_once(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Running once...")

    def run_forever(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Running forever...")
```

To run once;

```
Controller(target=Controller.run_once).start()
```

To run forever;

```
Controller(target=Controller.run_forever).start()
```